# Assign retrieved data from firebase to property angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase

```
import fb from 'firebase';

import { User } from '../models/user';

export class AuthService {

    private userId : string;
    private user : User;


    recoverUser(userId : string){
    var user,
        userRef = fb.database().ref('users').child(userId);
        userRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        user = new User(snapshot.val()["email"], snapshot.val()["tipo_usuario"], snapshot.val()["username"]);
        // this.user = user // ???
        console.log(user);
    });

  }

    getUser(){
      return this.user;
    }
}
```

The console.log() shows the correct value, but it can't assign the user to "this.user"(Cannot set property 'user' of null) and I can't get this value out of this function.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: what do you see inside the console? it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        let userRef = fb.database().ref('users').child(userId);
        userRef.on('value', snapshot => this.user = snapshot.val());
```

This is the correct way to solve this.

Closed